# What's the relation between JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that JavaScript is a scripting language, while HTML is a markup language. HTML allows the use to create content for a web app to view in their browser, but what does this have to do with JavaScript?

I'm just confused how they work together. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Among other things, JavaScript can be (and often is) used to _manipulate_ the HTML markup after it has been sent to the end user's browser, which HTML itself is not capable of doing.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript -> Use in web pages

Comment: You can use the Domain Specific Language HTML to describe the initial Document Object Model Javascript is then able to operate on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, but I think Michael's explanation helped most.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript manipulates HTML content in different ways.
With Javascript you can change all HTML elements, and control this behavior.

Comment: This is more of a comment... not an answer...